# log file for each thread ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, logging

I am new to ruby and I am facing a situation.

I have 3 classes and I am creating 1 Thread for each class. The problem is that, I have same function used by 3 classes which does not belong to either class and is in a separate file.

I am using ruby-1.9.3 Logger. I want to create a separate log file for each Thread, how am I supposed to do that?

Comment: You can get current thread id by doing, for example, `Thread.current.object_id`. Then you can use this id to make a log file name.

Comment: I did this, and I find it as a good idea, but only thing is I want to give a name to the log file so that it can be understood what class that log file is for!

So I tried this, Thread.current[:name] = "A" while creating the thread, but when it reached the function in other class, it is not able to retrieve by Thread.current[:name]
Am I missing something to retrieve that value?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible that you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

- Initialize a logger in each class, for example in a class method with caching.
- Add a `logger` argument to the methods you use from the 3 classes.
- Pass the current logger as parameter every time you use these methods.

Comment: I cannot modify the class definition, have to come up with a way without modifying it